# Overloading return types

Tags: c#

Is the following method overloaded?

```
class A
{
  Public void display(int a, int b)
  {
     console.write(a+b); 
  }

  Public int display(int a, int b)
  {
    return a+b; //return a+b value
  }  
}
```

Comment: You need different parameter types, how should .NET otherwise know which method you want to call? The return type doesn't matter. That's why it doesn't compile (apart from the syntax).

Answer (score 1):

the return type doesn't affect the method's signature. So your code will not compile, either the type or number of parameters should be different in order to make it compile.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. can you please tell me where can we do validations in MVC4?